# Custom info window code to display youtube videos no longer working

Tags: carto, infowindow, youtube

We have some info window code that displays youtube videos that just stopped working. We haven't made any changes and the videos in the info windows had been working great.

Anyway, we used the following basic instructions to get the videos in the info window:

You can embed YouTube or any other web content that can be published with an IFRAME directly in your infowindows. Just like embedding your images, you can embed your videos. For example, if you have a column containing YouTube video URLs called youtube_embed_link, the HTML would look like this,

```
<p>
  <iframe width="188" src="{{youtube_embed_link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</p>
```

Our youtube_embed_link looks like this:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/UJDlDN9LGKU

Any reason this would stop working?

Comment: It seems like a reasonable question. The dashboard of CartoDB was changed today, so there may have been other code changes. I don't work for them, so I am only guessing, but I think the downvote was unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are no longer supported in infowindows after some security changes in the platform. In order to add them, now it's required to build your own custom infowindows with CartoDB.js.

Comment: I tried to give you an upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet. Thanks for the quick reply.